# Symfony 2 not serving assets produced by assetic in prod (behind a reverse proxy, but it does using the controller in debug mode)

Tags: symfony, reverse-proxy, assetic

I have a Symfony 2 installation, living behind a reverse proxy.

When

- the `use_controller` flag is set to `true` (in app/config/config.yml)
- the kernel is instantiated in debug mode: `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`

the assets are served with no problem, but after switching off the debug-mode and disabling the assetic controller, I can't manage to get my assets served.

Note that:

- assets are correctly generated (I checked) through: `app/console assetic:dump --no-debug --env=prod`
- templates are rendered and served correctly (i.e. i get my html pages, but with no assets loaded)
- the URLs of the assets seems to be correct.
- I must use a reverse proxy since I can't move Symfony to the main server, it needs to stay on a different one for many reasons
- I also already tried to set

> ```
> framework:
>     trust_proxy_headers: true</li>
> ```
>
> with the same results.

In particular, Symfony's routing renders templates for routes like:

`http://<mycompany>.com/app/<routing>/...`

Where `/app` is the keyword that tells to Apache to reverse proxy the request, followed by Symfony's usual routing.

The assets link in my pages are like: 
`http://<mycompany>.com/app/css/a8d432.css` <-- file exists in the `web` dir, generated by assetic:dump, but they're not served.

I configured Symfony behind the reverse proxy following [this howto](http://blog.viison.com/post/21026843634/running-symfony2-behind-a-reverse-proxy-using-a-custom)